# Why am I prompted for input more times than I am expecting?

Tags: c, logic, logical-operators

I have to create a program that solves the following gate circuit. However, something goes wrong during program execution, because I am prompted to input eight times instead of six. Please, only provide solutions that involve changes in the main function, and not others.

Here is a diagram of the circuit problem I have to solve:
[image: Circuit problem I have to solve]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*CallBack)(int, int);

typedef struct gate {
    CallBack f;  
    struct gate * in1 ;  
    struct gate * in2 ; 
} Gate;  

int getinput() {  
    int x;  
    scanf("%d", &x);  
    return x; 
} 

int myand (int a, int b) {  
    return a * b; 
} 

int myor (int a, int b) {  
    return a + b>0;
}

int mynand (int a, int b) {  
    return !(a * b); 
} 

int mynor (int a, int b) {  
    return a + b<=0;
}

int myxor (int a, int b) {
    return a!=b;
}   


Gate * creategate(CallBack f) {  
    Gate * temp ;  
    temp = malloc(sizeof (Gate));  
    temp->f = f;  
    temp->in1 = NULL;  
    temp->in2 = NULL;    
    return temp; 
} 

int eval(Gate *x) {  
    int a, b;  
    if (x->in1 != NULL)    
        a = eval(x->in1);  
    if (x->in2 != NULL)   
        b = eval(x->in2);  
    if (x->in1==NULL && x->in2 == NULL)   
        return (x->f)(0,0);  
    else   
        return (x->f)(a,b); 
} 

int main( ) {  
    Gate * gate1_ptr, * gate2_ptr, * gate3_ptr, * gate4_ptr, * gate5_ptr, * gate6_ptr;
    Gate * a_ptr, * b_ptr, * c_ptr, * d_ptr, * e_ptr, * f_ptr;    

    gate1_ptr = creategate(mynor);  
    gate2_ptr = creategate(myand);  
    gate3_ptr = creategate(myor);
    gate4_ptr = creategate(mynand);
    gate5_ptr = creategate(myxor);
    gate6_ptr = creategate(myor);

    printf("Enter six inputs, split by enter:\n");

    a_ptr = creategate(getinput);  
    b_ptr = creategate(getinput);  
    c_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    d_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    e_ptr = creategate(getinput);
    f_ptr = creategate(getinput); 

    gate1_ptr->in1 = a_ptr;  
    gate1_ptr->in2 = b_ptr;
    gate2_ptr->in1 = c_ptr;  
    gate2_ptr->in2 = d_ptr;
    gate3_ptr->in1 = e_ptr;  
    gate3_ptr->in2 = f_ptr;  

    gate4_ptr->in1 = gate1_ptr;
    gate4_ptr->in2 = gate2_ptr;
    gate5_ptr->in1 = gate2_ptr;
    gate5_ptr->in2 = gate3_ptr;  

    gate6_ptr->in1 = gate4_ptr;
    gate6_ptr->in2 = gate5_ptr;

    printf("%d", eval(gate6_ptr));    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Prompted? How? You have only one prompt.

Comment: Start by making those functions either use boolean logic (that is `&&`, `||`, `!` etc) or bitwise logic, instead of the unreadable arithmetic. Your current code has various bugs. for example `!=` is not the same as XOR. `1!=2` gives 1, but `1 ^ 2` gives 3.

Comment: This code shouldn't be prompting you at all since you don't actually call `getinput`.

Comment: Reading warnings should help

Comment: By prompted I mean I can input 8 times instead of 6. The inputs are only 0 and 1, so there is no problem in the actual function of the gate functions.

Comment: @dbush yes it does, but not correctly. It's in the `eval` And there lays a huge problem: `Callback` doesn't match the argument list of `getinput` whatsoever. A big phat warning should  be shown on those `creategate(getinput)` calls, that apparently the OP is completely ignoring.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ZL3OkGr.jpg

Comment: There are no warnings. I have enabled them all and they are being treated as errors.

Comment: But `getinput` is actually called 8 times. Put this as first line of `getinput` : `static int nbcalled;  printf("Getinput: %d\n", nbcalled++);`

Comment: Why are you passing `getinput` as a callback to your `creategate` anyway?

Comment: It is indeed called 8 times. And that's the problem. I can't see why it is called 8 times.

Comment: Also why are you passing `Gate` pointers as callbacks?

Comment: What arguments does a `Callback` take ? Now, what arguments does `getinput` take? Do you not see a problem ? Was that your intent ? `getinput` does take arbitrary arguments (e.g it's not `getinput(void)`, it's `getinput()`, so I suppose it's feasible it *could* work, but was that *really* your intent? If you *really* want to see the call chains, fire this in a debugger, set a breakpoint on `getinput` and examine the call stack on each trip. There are only eight of them. It's not going to take long.

Comment: `getinput()` It is called 8 times because gate 2 is evaluated twice - once for gate 4 input 2 and once for gate 5 input 1.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you try to evaluate one of your "input" terms, you ask for input from the user.  Since `gate2_ptr` is referenced by two gates, its value is evaluated twice, and each of its inputs is evaluated twice.  This results in the two extra input prompts when ou run the program.

You should ask for the input values when the inputs are created, not when they are evaluated.

Unrelated, but some compilers will issue a warning for `creategate(getinput)` because `creategate` expects a pointer to a function that takes two `int` parameters, while `getinput` expects none.  In this instance, this is harmless because the extra parameters will be ignored by `getinput` and removed by the caller, but it does represent a potentially flawed design.  (If `getinput` would expect more parameters - like 3 `int`s - you'd get a different set of warnings and introduce more serious problems.)